# Node.js error invalid value for schema Array path

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I can't figure out what is wrong with this code:

act.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

var ActSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String },
    runs: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Run' }],
  }
)

export default mongoose.model('Act', ActSchema);
```

scheduleRun.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import Act from './act'

var ScheduleRunSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    act: [Act.ActSchema]
  }
)

export default mongoose.model('ScheduleRun', ScheduleRunSchema);
```

It gives the following error:

> TypeError: Invalid value for schema Array path `act`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are exporting a Mongoose model but trying to use the schema.

If the model has already been registered then you can get the schema like this:

```
var ActSchema = mongoose.model('Act').schema
```

Or you can try exporting your schema as a named export from ***act.js***:

```
...

export var ActSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String },
    runs: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Run' }],
  }
)

...
```

...and then import the schema to ***scheduleRun.js***:

```
...

import { ActSchema } from './act'

var ScheduleRunSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    act: [ActSchema]
  }
)

...
```